# Document does not have a root element in Custom xslt map during runtime, but not in Debug

Tags: xml, xslt, dictionary, biztalk

Consider an orchestration which takes in an HL7v2 message, then combines the MSH/Body/ZSegments into one HL7v2 XML schema. This HL7v2 XML message is then run through a Map in the orchestration. The map is assigned a custom XSLT file, instead of just using the GUI mapper. The destination schema for the final mapping is actually just a generic schema that contains nothing other than an "any" element.

Despite this, the XSLT is actually (supposed to be) mapping to a CDA document that later gets validated, so at this point we don't want to follow the schema just yet (the xslt actually has some logic in it depending on the type of Document)

This mapping is where the error occurs, I've debugged it and the orchestration makes it all the way up to the transform, then stops with a

`Document does not have a root element.` in the event logs, as well when I run the map in Visual Studio with the "Test Map" command, the same error occurs, but doesn't say what has the root node missing...I have a feeling it must be related to the generic schema, as the "Test Map" found some errors in my test XML instance (meaning it's actually reading the input).

The output file from the Test Map just contains:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>` with guess what, no root node!

The transform happens fine and when run in debug mode in **XMLSpy**. AND this all worked in BizTalk **2010**...**we just converted everything to BizTalk 2013**, did nothing other then open the projects in Visual Studio 2012 (to convert to BizTalk 2013 format) and deploy to BTS via Visual Studio. No code was changed, it all compiled fine, there were no errors or warnings in the conversions of the projects.

My question is, what has changed? Has .Net changed how it does XSLT/Schema handling in 4.5? Has BizTalk 2013 made any changes in this respect?

**EDIT with More info**
I decided to try "Debug Map" in Visual Studio 2012 (where Test Map doesn't work). And the transformation happened without a hitch...Test Map still fails. The only other bit of info is in the output window during "Debug Map" I notice it's loading System.Xml from the Microsoft.Net GAC:

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll`

I also just happened to find this:

[What's new in BizTalk 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj248703.aspx)

`The Mapper uses the XSLCompiledTransform class. Previous BizTalk Server versions used the XslTransform class, which is obsolete.`

Which I'm guessing is the root of my problem, but damned if I know how to fix...

**[Update]**

I wrote a quick app that confirms our XSLT works fine using XslTransform, but fails with the `Document does not have a root element.` when using XslCompiledTransform class.

Anyone have an tips on debugging the XslCompiledTransform?

**[Update2]**
After mucking around with the test app, I found it all came down to this line in the XSL file:

`<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>`

I ended up getting the error `Whitespace cannot be stripped from documents that have already been loaded. Provide the input as an XmlReader instead`

So, I did what it says, in my test app and it worked! However, I can't do so (or don't know how to specify) in BizTalk, as I don't have control over that.

Is there still a way to strip the whitespace at a document level in BizTalk? If not, the tabs and carriage returns mess up the data and documents fail validation.

Comment: Did you want to strip white space in the output of the map or the input documents? Did you consider a custom pipeline component to sanitize your inputs?

Comment: It was/is on the input documents, which basically removes it from the output as well though exclusion based on nothing being present. What I ended up doing was using a bunch of `[normalize-space(.)] ` throughout the XSLT. I'm still looking for a better way, but for now it works.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but let me at least comment on your last question:

> Is there still a way to strip the whitespace at a document level in BizTalk? If not, the tabs and carriage returns mess up the data and documents fail validation.

Apparently, the Microsoft XML .NET tool stack does not allow you to strip whitespace when the document is already loaded. This is clearly a violation of the XSLT standard, but what else is new, so let's not go there. There is, however, a relatively simple way to strip whitespace in XSLT without using `xsl:strip-space`.

**Stripping/normalizing space without xsl:strip-space:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ext="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="stripped">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/" mode="strip-whitespace" />
        </xsl:variable>

        <!-- micro-pipeline of input document, now without redundant whitespace -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ext:node-set($stripped)/*" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <!-- start your regular processing here in the default mode -->
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- copy idiom, copies any input nodes unchanged -->
    <xsl:template match="node() | attribute::node()" mode="strip-whitespace">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | attribute::node()" mode="strip-whitespace" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- normalize space on text-nodes. Chagne this appropriately 
        if you only want to remove trailing/leading whitespace -->
    <xsl:template match="text()" mode="strip-whitespace">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```